# linq "let" translation

Tags: c#, linq

I understand that when the C# compiler sees a [linq query comprehension](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqsyntax.aspx), it basically does a straight translation to the corresponding Linq Extension methods and lambdas. i.e.

```
from x in list
select x.property
```

gets translated to:

```
list.Select(x => x.property)
```

my question is what do `let` clauses get translated to.  for example how would this get translated by the compiler.

```
from x in list
let v = SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx
select v
```

(p.s. i know this could be reduced to just `select SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx` but i want to know how this is done in general)

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In this particular case, it gets translated to:

```
list.Select( x => SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx );
```

But there may be a more complex case, such as:

```
from x in list
let v = SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx
where v > 10 && v+5 < 50 && SomeFunc(v) == "str"
select x
```

Will translate to:

```
list.Where( x => 
    {
        var v = SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx;
        return v > 10 && v+5 < 50 && SomeFunc(v) == "str";
    }
)
```

In other words, the `let` keyword is a way to minimize and/or optimize your query. That is, without the `let` keyword you would have to write:

```
from x in list
where
    SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx > 10 &&
    SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx+5 < 50 &&
    SomFunc(SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx) == "str"
select x
```

Resulting in possible triple evaluation of the same expression.

## **Update**, following a question in comment.

**First**, what's so scary about "block expressions"? They're just a shorthand for arbitrary delegate. That is, the following expression:

```
Func<string,int> f = 
    s =>
    {
        var ln = s.Length;
        return ln/2;
    }
```

Is equivalent to the following:

```
int CompilerGeneratedMethodIdentifier0( string s )
{
    var ln = s.Length;
    return ln/2;
}

...

Func<string, int> f = new Func<string, int>( CompilerGeneratedMethodIdentifier0 );
```

**Second**, what's so *special* about "block expressions"? Did you know that mmm... let's call them "*non-block*" expressions also expand to the very same code? That is, the simple code `new Func<string,int>( s => s.Length/2 )` is absolute equivalent to:

```
int CompilerGeneratedMethodIdentifier0( string s )
{
    return s.Length/2;
}

...

new Func<string, int>( CompilerGeneratedMethodIdentifier0 );
```

**Third**, what's so *non-linqy* about "block expressions"? LINQ uses delegates all over the place, and it doesn't really matter to LINQ what exact shortcut you use to represent those delegates.

In particular, your expression `from a in list where a.SomeProp > 10 select new { A = a, B = a.GetB() }` gets translated into the following:

```
class AnonymousType0
{
    public MyClass A { get; set; }
    public othertype B { get; set; }
}

bool WhereFunc0( MyClass a )
{
    return a.SomeProp > 10;
}

AnonymousType0 SelectResultFunc0( MyClass a )
{
    AnonymousType0 result = new AnonymousType0();
    result.A = a;
    result.B = a.GetB();
    return result;
}

...

list
    .Where( new Func<MyClass,bool>( WhereFunc0 ) )
    .Select( new Func<MyClass,AnonymousType0>( SelectResultFunc0 ) );
```

**Fourth**, to get understanding like this, one can just play with the language and explore.

**And fifth**, if the previous advice doesn't work for you for one reason or another, you always have [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). Very useful tool, everybody should have one.

Comment: huh, i never would've expected it to resolve to a block expression, Block Expressions just don't seem very linq'y to me.  Do you have a source for this, or is it just a guess?

Comment: thanks for the hard work, i guess when i said that i didn't think block expressions were very "linq'y", it was because i associate (incorrectly) block expressions with side-effect causing expressions (which definitely isn't linq'y), but clearly i was wrong :).  Thanks again

Comment: I can only give one +1 :( I heartily second point four: play with your language, a truth for any (programming) language.

Comment: It doesn't resolve to a block expression, it resolves to an extra select wrapping the `let` variable along with the existing variables in a new anonymous type. In answer to `what's so scary about "block expressions"`, they can't be translated into expression trees, so e.g. this would be useless in LINQ to SQL. `Use one's brain`, indeed.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net), you can write the query and hit the lamba symbol to see what the output will look like.  For example I took this query:

```
var names = new[] { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay" }.AsQueryable();

var results = 
    from n in names
    let n1 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(n)
    select n1;

results.Dump();
```

And it output the following:

```
System.String[]
   .Select (
      n => 
         new  
         {
            n = n, 
            n1 = String.IsNullOrEmpty (n)
         }
   )
   .Select (temp0 => temp0.n1)
```

So it does indeed look like the let is translated to a temp value as anonymous, and then consumed in the outer select statement.

I love LINQPad for the ability to write the query and see how it would translate.

Comment: I thought there had to be an anonymous type or else where would the v be stored temporarily...

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess since I rarely use query syntax:

```
list.Select(x => new { v = SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx(x) });
```

The let is just assigning a new var v the select is returning it.

It could also be the following if you didn't want an anon object with v in it:

```
var v = list.Select(x => SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx(x));
```

Comment: Wow negative votes for giving an explination? At least post why or you down vote doesn't help informing me of what I could do differently.

Comment: Your guess is wrong.  The OP's code will not create an anonymous type.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen interesting, if it doesn't then how is `select v` valid? isn't `v` storing the result of `SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx`? I haven't used it ever before so it could have been a bad assumption but interested to know the why now like OP.  I guess it's not anonymous since `SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx` would be returning a known type?

Comment: @Kelsey you can write any expression after select. In particular, you could write `select x+2`. Does it mean that an anonymous type will be created with a single member named `x+2`? Think.

Comment: Yes, v has the result of `SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx`.  However, there is no reason to create an actual anonymous type with a `v` field.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin yes I got it. I realize it as I was typing the other edit :)  Will adjust as there is no point leaving an incorrect bit in my response.

Answer (score -1):

```
list.Select(x => SomeComplexExpressionDependingOnx );
```

In general, [`let`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976%28VS.90%29.aspx) basically works as a `readonly` variable holding a range.