# Let Query syntax in Method Syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to translate a Linq Query example into Lambda and I am having trouble translating the Let clause.

```
var numbers = from n in arrayOfNumbers
              orderby n
              let evenOrOdd = (n % 2 == 0) ? "Even" : "Odd"
              group n by evenOrOdd into nums
              orderby nums.Count()
              select nums;
```

This example does work as intended:

```
var numbers = arrayOfNumbers.OrderBy(n => n)
                            .GroupBy(n => (n % 2 == 0) ? "Even" : "Odd")
                            .OrderBy(k => k.Count());
```

Both the query and the example above can be printed the following way:

```
foreach (var item in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}");
    foreach (var i in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"  {i}");
    }
}
```

But I wanted to make it a bit more readable and extract the condition somehow, so I tried this (got the idea from this post [LINQ Let operator with lambda syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577895/linq-let-operator-with-lambda-syntax)) but it

```
var numbers = arrayOfNumbers.OrderBy(n => n)
                            .Select(evenOrOdd => new
                            {
                                Number = evenOrOdd,
                                Key = (evenOrOdd % 2 == 0) ? "Even" : "Odd"
                            })
                            .GroupBy(n => n.Key)
                            .OrderBy(k => k.Count());
```

And now the printing is a bit changed, I need to specificly say that I want to print the Number.

```
foreach (var item in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}");
    foreach (var i in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"  {i.Number}");
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to translate this query into lambda syntax with the condition somehow "extracted"?

Comment: FYI That's query syntax and you want to translate it to method syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your GroupBy like that, so it shows your 'let' intermediary step, with indentical result :

```
var numbers = arrayOfNumbers
    .OrderBy(n => n)
    .GroupBy(n => {
         var evenOrOdd = (n % 2 == 0);
         return evenOrOdd ? "Even" : "Odd";
    })
    .OrderBy(k => k.Count());
```

Basicaly, you can use complex function as your lambda expression, as soon as the parameter and return type are correct.

In this case, you can't use the simplified syntax so it's a bit more verbose, you have to use the `return` statement and brackets like your usual methods.

A more detailed explanation in a similar question is here :

[linq "let" translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002502/linq-let-translation)

Comment: Thanks it didnt even cross my mind to try and do it inside the GroupBy method :)

Comment: @Darkbound, yes (and as more detailed in the question I linked above), and you can have any function method as your lambda, you just need to clearly use a `return` statement in this case. But at the end, you can see that this just a lambda taking `n` and returning a `string`, so all's good ! Glad it helped.

Comment: so basicly whenever I want to use let in Lambda(method) syntax, I simply need to expand the anonymous method inside the Linq method (like we did here with the group) and create my let (var) variable inside it and return the correct type at the end?

Comment: @Darkbound yes, exactly ! The usual notation `x => expression`  is a just syntactic sugar (shorthand) for the one-liner function `x => { return expression; }`, and nothing prevent you to define a more complex function with several lines of code before the return. You can also define your lambda elsewhere, and just pass the `Func<T1, T2>` object reference, if this helps you be more clear or for reusing the same in several queries.

Comment: Example for my last sentence : `Func<int, string> evenOrOdd = (int n) => n % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd";`, and then the GroupBy part can be written simlpy like this : `arrayOfNumbers.GroupBy(evenOrOdd)` . I find it somehow more readable, especially if you have several queries using the same logic.